# django: Proper way to recover from IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.1

### What's the proper way to recover from an `IntegrityError`, or any other errors that could leave my transactions screwed up without using manual transaction control?

In my application, I'm running into problems with `IntegrityError`s that I want to recover from, that screw up later database activity, leaving me with:

```
DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`
```

for all database activity after ignoring `IntegrityErrors`.

This block of code should reproduce the error I'm seeing

```
from django.db import transaction

try:
    MyModel.save() # Do a bad save that will raise IntegrityError
except IntegrityError:
    pass

MyModel.objects.all() # raises DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#handling-exceptions-within-postgresql-transactions), the solution to recover from an `IntegrityError` is by rolling back the transaction. But the following code results in a `TransactionManagementError`.

```
from django.db import transaction

try:
    MyModel.save()
except IntegrityError:
    transaction.rollback() # raises TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management

MyModel.objects.all() # Should work
```

---

**EDIT:** I'm confused by the message from the `TransactionManagementError`, because if in my `except` I do a:

```
connection._cursor().connection.rollback()
```

instead of the django `transaction.rollback()`, the `MyModel.objects.all()` succeeds, which doesn't make sense if my code "isn't under transaction management". It also doesn't make sense that code that isn't under transaction management (which I assume means it's using autocommit), can have transactions that span multiple queries.

**EDIT #2:** I'm aware of using manual transaction control to be able to recover from these errors, but shouldn't I be able to recover *without* manual transaction control? My understanding is that if I'm using autocommit, there should only be one write per transaction, so it should **not** affect later database activity.

**EDIT #3:** This is a couple years later, but in django 1.4 (not sure about later versions), another issue here was that `Model.objects.bulk_create()` doesn't honor autocommit behavior.

#### Versions:

- Django:   1.4 (`TransactionMiddleWare` is **not** enabled)
- Python:   2.7
- Postgres: 9.1

Comment: Did you try the [Savepoint rollback](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#savepoint-rollback) suggestion? The documentation isn't clear, but it may be that you need to be in `transaction.commit_manually` mode for `transaction.rollback` to work. See the pattern [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually).

Comment: I figured that might be the case, but it'd be nice to not have to use manual transaction control for every single save in my project

Comment: The savepoints won't help me because I'm using the default autocommit behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's default commit mode is AutoCommit. In order to do rollback, you need to wrap the code doing the work in a transaction. [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transaction-management-in-views)]

```
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    # Your code here. Errors will auto-rollback.
```

To get database level autocommit, you will require the following option in your DATABASES settings dictionary.

```
'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True,}
```

Alternately, you can use explicit savepoints to roll back to. [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints)]

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def viewfunc(request):

  a.save()
  # open transaction now contains a.save()
  sid = transaction.savepoint()

  b.save()
  # open transaction now contains a.save() and b.save()

  if want_to_keep_b:
      transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
      # open transaction still contains a.save() and b.save()
  else:
      transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
      # open transaction now contains only a.save()

  transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I don't want to resort to manual transaction control for every save. Not sure there's any other way, but I'm still confused as to why later database activity is affected by a failed previous save if I'm using autocommit.

Comment: I'm updating my question to specify how to recover *without* using manual transaction control.

Comment: Well then, the answer is probably to turn on database level autocommit. `'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True,}`

Comment: One last thing, though: Do you know why the transaction wasn't automatically getting rolled back on errors when I was using just django level autocommit? I might make a question for this.

Comment: Django autocommit != Postgres Autocommit. Neither will auto-rollback.

Comment: I'd say their docs are pretty misleading, then: 

`This is much like the auto-commit setting for most databases. As soon as you perform an action that needs to write to the database, Django produces the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements and then does the COMMIT. There’s no implicit ROLLBACK.`

Comment: to update the answer, as of django 3.2 (probably earlier) `commit_on_success` doesn't exist any more on `transaction` as the documentation indicates (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/), the use of `transaction.atomic()` is perfect to handle `IntegrityError` in a try/except block